# How do I combine those two queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the products in it and the date when they are added or when they leaved our catalog. And the qprod Table which is a calender table with all dates from 2018-2025

I want to make a graph with the amount of new and amount of leaving products for every month. When I run one of those queries on its own it gives me the month and the amount of produtcs that were added/ left the catalog.
Like this:

```
Year |Month |NewProd  
2018 | 1    | 5  
2018 | 2    | 10  
2018 | 3    | 2
```

But I want these amounts in one table, so one column with newprods and a column with oldprods.
Like this

```
Year |Month |NewProd | OldProd   
2018 | 1    | 5      | 1  
2018 | 2    | 10     | 0  
2018 | 3    | 2      | 3
```

Can someone help me combining those two queries to one query?

I'm using Microsoft Sql Server management studio

```
Select year, month, Count(prodid) as NewProd
from (select DATEPART("yyyy", datum) AS year,
             DATEPART("mm", datum)   AS month,
             DatePart("dd", datum)   AS Day,
             DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(datum), MONTH(datum), Day(datum)) as MonthDate 
       from qProds
      ) dates left join
      Products
      on products.lnewprod = dates.Monthdate 
 Group By year, month
 Order By Year, month
```

And

```
Select year, month, Count(prodid) as Old_prod
from (select DATEPART("yyyy", datum) AS year,
             DATEPART("mm", datum)   AS month ,
             DatePart("dd", datum)   AS Day,
             DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(datum), MONTH(datum), Day(datum)) as MonthDate 
      from qProds
     ) dates left join
     products
     on products.loldprod = dates.Monthdate 
Group By year, month
Order By Year, month
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would definitely help.

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this. You could use subqueries or join the table again with a different alias as dates and use those columns

Comment: I tried to do it with an alias, but I did not succeed, can you show me or explain me how I need to do that?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I added a little bit of sample data and desired results

Comment: i can't see any sample data - only wanted result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what `qprod` is.  But the following query should return the results you want:

```
select year(v.dte), month(v.dte), sum(v.isnew), sum(v.isold)
from products p cross apply
     (values (p.lnewprod, 1, 0), (p.loldprod, 0, 1)
     ) v(dte, isnew, isold)
group by year(v.dte), month(v.dte)
order by year(v.dte), month(v.dte);
```

Note that if a month has no "old" or "new" records, it will not be in the result set.  This can be fixed with a calendar table.  It is not clear to me that `qprod` is such a table.

Comment: Qprod is a calender table in deed, with all dates from 2018 to 2025

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
select A.yr as Year,A.mn as Month, A.NewProd, B.Old_prod from (
Select year as yr, month as mn, Count(prodid) as NewProd
from (select DATEPART("yyyy", datum) AS year,
             DATEPART("mm", datum)   AS month,
             DatePart("dd", datum)   AS Day,
             DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(datum), MONTH(datum), Day(datum)) as MonthDate 
       from qProds
      ) dates left join
      Products
      on products.lnewprod = dates.Monthdate 
 Group By year, month
 Order By Year, month)A
full join 
select * from 
(Select year as yrr, month as mnt, Count(prodid) as Old_prod
from (select DATEPART("yyyy", datum) AS year,
             DATEPART("mm", datum)   AS month ,
             DatePart("dd", datum)   AS Day,
             DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(datum), MONTH(datum), Day(datum)) as MonthDate 
      from qProds
     ) dates left join
     products
     on products.loldprod = dates.Monthdate 
Group By year, month
Order By Year, month)B
on (A.yr = B.yrr and A.mn = B.mnt and A.NewProd = B.Old_prod)
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to union your both statements and then sum the counts to get your wanted result:

```
SELECT year, month, sum(NewProd) as NewProd, sum(OldProd) as OldProd
FROM (
    Select year, month, Count(prodid) as NewProd, 0 as OldProd
    from (select DATEPART("yyyy", datum) AS year,
                 DATEPART("mm", datum)   AS month,
                 DatePart("dd", datum)   AS Day,
                 DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(datum), MONTH(datum), Day(datum)) as MonthDate 
           from qProds
          ) dates left join
          Products
          on products.lnewprod = dates.Monthdate 
     Group By year, month
    UNION
    Select year, month, 0 as NewProd, Count(prodid) as OldProd
    from (select DATEPART("yyyy", datum) AS year,
                 DATEPART("mm", datum)   AS month ,
                 DatePart("dd", datum)   AS Day,
                 DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(datum), MONTH(datum), Day(datum)) as MonthDate 
          from qProds
         ) dates left join
         products
         on products.loldprod = dates.Monthdate 
    Group By year, month) as combined_counts
GROUP BY year, month
ORDER BY year, month
```

not tested.